# CompiledCode.Execute takes a long time during the first iteration

Tags: c#, mono, ironpython

I'm embedding small scripts in a c# application.
To increase performance I compile them when the application starts.

```
public CompiledCode CompileScript(string script)
{
    return engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script).Compile();
}
```

The CompiledCode instances are then stored in a Dictionary so I can reuse them later.

When the time has come to execute them, I use something like:

```
result = code.Execute(scope);
```

Where scope is an instance of `ScriptScope` maintained by a simple helper class.
That scope is set up when an instance of the helper is created so that variables and assemblies available to the scripts are added properly:

```
if (variables != null)
{
    scope = engine.CreateScope(variables);
}
else
{
    scope = engine.CreateScope();
}
```

```
if (assemblies != null)
{                
    assemblies.ForEach(a => scope.Engine.Runtime.LoadAssembly(a));
}
```

Basically, a list of assemblies is passed to the constructor of the helper class and I reuse the instance of the helper class in various places. (Not a static class, as I do need multiple helper instances for specific scenarios, but in the context of this question we are talking about a single instance)

When using this on a normal PC the overhead of compiling/running the code is neglectable.
However, I'm running this on a `RaspberryPI` and noticed that the first time a specific script is executed, it takes a very long time. (Easily up to 40 seconds for a 2 line script)

Subsequent executions of the same `CompiledCode` instances execute really fast (200ms).

So I have code that has already been compiled (oddly that first compilation is very fast as well), but the first call to Execute() on a given `CompiledCode` instance takes ages.

Now I'm wondering, what is it that `Execute()` does the first time and is there a way to perform whatever it is doing at an earlier time without actually executing the code? 
There seems to be an additional step between compiling and actually running the code.

I was thinking maybe it's related to the fact that I reuse the scope defined by the
helper class, but of course if I just use the default scope on execute
I don't have any of the variables and assembly references.

**Update:**

> Running it on a RaspberryPI means I'm using Mono. 
> More specifically
>   Mono 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-8)
> I cannot update Mono as I'm relying on a
>   very specific version of MonoGame
> that only works with this exact version of Mono at the time of writing.

Comment: Have you tried looking at it using a performance profiler? Are there any exceptions? Have you looked at which assemblies are being loaded/JITed and how long that takes?

Comment: No, it's very difficult to hook up a profiler, it only occurs when running on the Raspberry, so no debugger there and the mono profiler doesn't help me much either. The odd thing is it only happens once per CompiledCode and assembly/variable loading only occurs once, not for every instance of CompiledCode, so it's really the  first Execute that takes so long. The alternative is that I use MEF to support plugins instead of scripts

Comment: The Compile() method generates IL.  Which then has to be translated to machine code.  That needs to be done once, you are measuring how long that takes.  Mono doesn't have the fanciest jitter around but 40 seconds is rather a long time.  Long enough to suspect some kind of networking issue, it roughly matches the default tcp/ip connection timeout.

Comment: So.. the compile generated IL and then on the first execute that IL is translated to machine code, is that what you are saying? As for the networking issue, probably coincidence, as there is no networking involved) The scripts just get a value and apply transformations on that value before returning it. That transformation might be complex once deployed but during testing it's a simple  return value + 1 kind of thing

Comment: Also... can I somehow force it to do the translation to machine code up front? At the start of the app it's acceptable to have a delay (in this particular project) I know you can "cache" the generated machine code for an application, but I take it that doesn't apply to these scripts

Comment: If it is related to JIT, you could look at http://www.mono-project.com/AOT (and if that works on the raspberry pi). You probably should update your question+tags for the fact that mono is used.

Comment: @SimonOpelt while it does help general performance, it does not help me as the CompiledCode are IronPython script files that are/should be compiled at the start of the application. I did not know about AOT however, and find it very interesting for other projects as well, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hazarding a guess, I'd say that what's happening is that the IronPython assemblies are getting JITted. THe only issue is that there are other code paths that call into IronPython, and I don't know if Mono's JIT works on the assembly level or the type/method level. You could try doing AOT on the IronPython and DLR assemblies and see if that helps at all.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I'm thinking it's the jitting of the scripts itself that cause the issue as it happens once for every script